# SignalR sends hundreds of OnDisconnected events

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, redis, signalr

I have implemented Redis on AWS ElasticCache and I have 2 instances with Application Load Balancer.
For some unknown reason I'm receiving from the server hundreds of OnDisconnected events with unknown connections Id, whereas my client is still connected. The OnDisconnected function is triggered many times for unknown reason.

The Hub implementation:

`public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            return Clients.All.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }`

The client console:

`leave received in SignalRService: 66da6de3-3922-4c60-ae04-cd545033b671 time: 10/22/2019 9:20:31 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 03dc70d7-eb0e-41da-a35e-88f9f6c6fdea time: 10/22/2019 9:20:35 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: ff1d14b7-1274-4980-920f-2b8ad10ccdfa time: 10/22/2019 9:20:36 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: ba172e75-08da-45f7-98c4-2b0d5eed92a7 time: 10/22/2019 9:20:36 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 0737f9e6-09df-4b61-9432-1ffa3181bcee time: 10/22/2019 9:20:40 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 111a2307-930b-43e1-a99d-3938218a33ab time: 10/22/2019 9:21:01 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: b6a15d60-0eb5-4667-a115-f05990b3558c time: 10/22/2019 9:21:05 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 66da6de3-3922-4c60-ae04-cd545033b671 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:06 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: c855a158-f032-4fee-a75f-e9ecd20de022 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:06 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 78bb9f98-99bb-49c1-9d04-8e76d0d50ef6 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:10 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 0737f9e6-09df-4b61-9432-1ffa3181bcee time: 10/22/2019 9:21:11 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: c7ed549a-8c5d-4ed4-a804-821db4c49c44 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:11 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: ec593fa7-679f-418f-9735-e6e12e656835 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:23 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 91703612-41bc-4453-b0f3-296d7a93e95b time: 10/22/2019 9:21:36 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: d960b37a-59de-428a-83f9-bdadd214c98f time: 10/22/2019 9:21:36 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: cfe35c87-4204-42e2-99a2-1c83143854c7 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:40 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 66da6de3-3922-4c60-ae04-cd545033b671 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:40 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: 2c6ce648-b1fb-4a8b-858e-240abcef110a time: 10/22/2019 9:21:41 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: f2fdd418-4101-4258-80db-fa297d809171 time: 10/22/2019 9:21:45 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: dcec1f11-29fc-4773-9541-7afc877fd53f time: 10/22/2019 9:22:10 AM
main.dcf82d81fc00f4c3a4c2.js:1 leave received in SignalRService: c6a4bb05-e3b7-4c1e-a1cb-b366c829af7f time: 10/22/2019 9:22:10 AM`

Comment: Maybe this occurs when the client is switching transports so it disconnects and then connects with the new transport protocol.

Comment: This is common when multiple threads try to connect with the same identity context, as one thread connects, it kills the previous thread's connection, which then tries to re-connect. Check that nothing like that is going on